# How to call functions that aren't inside a module from the test module?

Tags: rust

These are the contents of my `src/lib.rs` file:

```
pub fn foo() {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        foo();
    }
}
```

When I run `cargo test`, I get the following error:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `foo` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         foo();
  |         ^^^ not found in this scope
```

How do I call `foo` from inside the `test` module?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/testing.html#the-tests-module

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `super::` to refer to the parent module:

```
fn it_works() {
    super::foo();
}
```

In Rust 2015, you can use `::` to refer to the root module of the crate:

```
fn it_works() {
    ::foo();
}
```

In Rust 2018, you can use `crate::` to refer to the root module of the crate:

```
fn it_works() {
    crate::foo();
}
```

Or, as `foo` may be used repeatedly, you could `use` it in the module:

```
mod tests {
    use foo;         // <-- import the `foo` from the root module
    // or
    use super::foo;  // <-- import the `foo` from the parent module

    fn it_works() {
        foo();
    }
}
```

For test modules, it's also common to import everything from the parent module:

```
mod tests {
    use super::*;  // <-- import everything from the parent module

    fn it_works() {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I put `use super::*` since I'm not worried about namespace clouding in my own crate.